# How to capture incorrect (corrupt) JSON records in (Py)Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

I have a **Azure Eventhub**, which is streaming data (in JSON format). 
I read it as a Spark dataframe, parse the incoming "body" with `from_json(col("body"), schema)` where `schema` is pre-defined. In code it, looks like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType().add(...) # define the incoming JSON schema 

df_stream_input = (spark
.readStream
.format("eventhubs")
.options(**ehConfInput)
.load()
.select(from_json(col("body").cast("string"), schema)
)
```

And now = if there is some **inconsistency between the incoming JSON's schema and the defined schema** (e.g. the source eventhub starts sending data in new format without notice), **the `from_json()` functions will not throw an error = instead, it will put `NULL` to the fields, which are present in my `schema` definition but not in the JSONs eventhub sends**.

I want to capture this information and log it somewhere (Spark's log4j, Azure Monitor, warning email, ...).

**My question is: what is the best way how to achieve this.**

Some of my thoughts:

1. First thing I can think of is to have a UDF, which checks for the `NULLs` and if there is any problem, it raise an Exception. I believe there it is not possible to send logs to log4j via PySpark, as the "spark" context cannot be initiated within the UDF (on the workers) and one wants to use the default:

   log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
   logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger('PySpark Logger')
2. Second thing I can think of is to use "foreach/foreachBatch" function and put this check logic there.

But I feel both these approaches are like.. like too much custom - I was hoping that Spark has something built-in for these purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** You have to do this check logic yourself using `foreach` or `foreachBatch` operators.

---

It turns out I was mistaken thinking that `columnNameOfCorruptRecord` option could be an answer. It will not work.

Firstly, it won't work due to [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L603):

```
case _: BadRecordException => null
```

And secondly due to [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/jsonExpressions.scala#L568) that simply disables any other parsing modes (incl. `PERMISSIVE` that seems to be used alongside `columnNameOfCorruptRecord` option):

```
new JSONOptions(options + ("mode" -> FailFastMode.name), timeZoneId.get))
```

In other words, your only option is to use the 2nd item in your list, i.e. `foreach` or `foreachBatch` and handle corrupted records yourself.

A solution could use `from_json` while keeping the initial `body` column. Any record with an incorrect JSON would end up with the result column `null` and `foreach*` would catch it, e.g.

```
def handleCorruptRecords:
  // if json == null the body was corrupt
  // handle it

df_stream_input = (spark
  .readStream
  .format("eventhubs")
  .options(**ehConfInput)
  .load()
  .select("body", from_json(col("body").cast("string"), schema).as("json"))
).foreach(handleCorruptRecords).start()
```

Comment: Ok :) thanks for the answers - maybe in future there will be some changes

Comment: @mLC I think I may have found another solution. Mind checking it out? :) You simply use `foreachBatch` and use `spark.read.json(batchDataFrame.rdd)`. That could work. Thanks for accepting my answer.